# Assign Unique id's to buttons in foreach loop

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am building online shopping website and at this time there are 3 products in it. Here's the sample of products.

[image]

First it is a image, product name, description, price, id and "Add to Cart" Button which is build programmatically and It is also dynamically. 
You can see that every product have its own Button which is also created through foreach loop.
I am confuse that how can I get those unique id's which I assigned to it? Means when I click on Add to Cart button, it give me id=3 in foreach loop.
Now, I want a help that how "Add to Cart" button identify that which product is clicked and then show all the specification of product and then Proceed according to it.
Here's the Sample of Code:
I am using 3-tier architecture for it and here's the sample of code:

```
DataSet ds=obj.searching_product();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt = ds.Tables["Register_Product"];
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    Literal li2 = new Literal();
    li2.Text = "<br/>";
    this.Panel1.Controls.Add(li2);
    Label lb1 = new Label();
    lb1.Text = dr["Name"].ToString();
    this.Panel1.Controls.Add(lb1);

    //Adding Here's Literal for price, Images and ID etc.

    Literal li4 = new Literal();
    li4.Text = "<br/>";
    this.Panel1.Controls.Add(li4);
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.Height = 19;
    btn.Width = 100;
    btn.Text = "Add to Cart";
    btn.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
    this.Panel1.Controls.Add(btn);
}
```

Comment: Can you include some code for the `foreach` that you have already?

Comment: Please post all your code (backend, html, javascript, etc). There's a few fairly simple approaches that can help you achieve what you're looking for.

Comment: Okay, Now, Please check it now.

Comment: Any reason you aren't simply using a repeating element with databinding that handles all of this event/id hookup for you? It almost seems like you're trying to use webforms without using webforms.

Comment: I agree. Use a Repeater or DataList control and check out the ItemCommand or you could also handle the button click directly and find the control within your template to get the ID.

Comment: I am new in asp.net and I have no idea that How to use Repeater?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few ways to do it, You can create an extension to `Button` class, with a a property to hold ID or a *simpler hack* could be to use the `ItemID` in Button's ID like:

```
Button btn = new Button();
btn.ID = "btnItem-" + ItemID;
```

Then extract the `ItemID` in event handler like:

```
void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button senderButton = sender as Button;
    int itemID = -1;
    if (senderButton != null && senderButton.ID.Contains('-'))
    {
        itemID = int.Parse(senderButton.ID.Split('-')[1]); //or int.TryParse (better)
        //work with itemID
    }
}
```

As a side note, a better option would be to create your own button class *(extending existing Button class)* and add a new property for ItemID, **Even better** option would be to use controls like `GridView` or `Repeater` controls using Data Binding.

Comment: How can i use ItemID? Means Button do not have that type of Property? And How can i use Repeater for it? Any Suggestion?

Comment: @Crazyzoar, yes Button doesn't have a property to hold `itemID` that is why store it in the `ID` property of your button, you are not using it anywhere so utilize it, *thats the hack*, for GridView/Repeater search, [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/403267/ShoppingCart-using-Gridview-in-ASP-NET) could be starting point.

Comment: Can you tell me that How can I get DIV id's from aspx page? Here's the Sample of Code:
div class='adds' id='0' style='float:left;padding:10px;'> </div>

How can I get that id 0 from Button?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you use a [Repeater](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeater.itemcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [DataList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datalist.itemcommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) control and check out the ItemCommand and button's [CommandName and CommandArgument](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button_properties(v=vs.110).aspx) or you could also handle the button click directly and find the control within your template to get the ID. Otherwise, if you don't want to use these controls, you'll have to come up with your own similar mechanism of on the client side, adding your event name and ID argument to hidden fields before posting back, then in your Page_Load checking for theses values and delegating it to the appropriate action.